# Angular Observable subscribes multiple times occasionally

Tags: angular, angular5

I see there are many questions already asked about this issue but still can't find correct solution.

I have a service for http request and subrcribe in the component.

It **sometimes** subscribes several times and send several http requests.

Sometimes it works fine so I am not sure what it depends on whether it is called several times or not.

[image: http request is called 3 times]

The first one is checking option. (I am not sure this is required or its because of CORS policy. Is there a way to avoid this too?)

[image: first request]

**And then the next two requests are the same and return the values twice.**

This is a big trouble for me.

This is my service and component code.

service.ts

```
getPartners(): Observable<Partner[]> {
    return this.http.get<Partner[]>(SERVER_API_URL + `api/partners`);
  }
```

component.ts

```
this.partnerService.getPartners()
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(partners => {
      this.partners = partners;
    });
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first call is due to your request is not simple. A simple request is those who match de following:

- GET / HEAD / POST
- Uses just a few values for headers: ex. Content-type, Accept-Language, Accept, etc.. (see list on the internet)
- no ReadableStream used.
- etc...

This means that, if you for example (typical case) use the auth by injecting an authorization header on the HTTP request, this call would turn into a NOT SIMPLE call and would fire a preflight call previous the original one (this the OPTIONS call). Wich is automatically fired by the browser, and you cannot stop/skip this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @alejoko

Comment: So what is the exact solution for multiple subscription?

Comment: humm i dont know why is doing the call twice after options.. where do you place the service call? onInit?

Comment: No, in a method.

Comment: onScroll(reachedEnd) {
    if (reachedEnd) {
      this.getPartners();
      this.appService.setReachedEnd(false);
    }
  }

The service is called in getPartners() method.

Comment: so.. i imagine that the method is called twice into this wrapper method... did you try to put a console log inmediatly after 'if (reachedEnd)'?

Comment: So to protect the method entry, initalize a boolean prop called reachedEndCall : boolean = false; at the class start. and use that prop as a locking door as folowing:  onScroll(reachedEnd) { if (reachedEnd && !this.reachedEndCall) {  this.getPartners(); this.reachedEndCall = true; this.appService.setReachedEnd(false); } }

Comment: And just assign back the false value on the subscribe when you have the data on hand:    .subscribe(partners => { this.reachedEndCall = false;
      this.partners = partners;
    });

Comment: In console, it logs 3 times for sure. So I guess you are right.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you for your help. @alejoko

Comment: The first request (called a preflight) will always happen because of CORS policy, as alejoko mentioned. The reason this happens is that the browser needs to interrogate the web site to ascertain what REST verbs are supported (GET,  PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH..) Also, in your pipe, you may want to consider using the take operator to take only the first result, like so, pipe(take(1)). I would advice using take over first.